# How can I write a loop that will start C_x at zero and increase them by 200

Tags: python, for-loop

```
if(core_count % 2) == 0:
   txt.write("\n")
   C_x = C_x + 200
   T_x = T_x + 200
```

this is what I have so far and I want a for-loop that starts c_x at zero and then adds 200 each iteraration

Comment: `for c_x in range(0, max_expected_value+200, 200):`? or `for i in range(1, max_iteration+1): c_x = i*200`?

Answer (score 0):

Using a `for` loop:

```py
max_val = 2000
for C_x in range(0, max_val + 1, 200):
    print(C_x)
```

Using a `while` loop:

```py
max_val = 2000
C_x = 0
while C_x <= max_val:
    print(C_x)
    C_x += 200
```

---

Output:

```
0
200
400
600
800
1000
1200
1400
1600
1800
2000
```